# Reference request: Universal central extension of $\operatorname{PSl}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is the braid group $\mathcal B_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, modular-group, central-extensions

$\DeclareMathOperator{\PSl}{PSl}$
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_between_B3_and_the_modular_group), the universal central extension of $\PSl_2(\mathbb Z)$ is given by the braid group $\mathcal B_3$ on three strands,
\begin{equation} \label{extension} \tag{1} 0 \to c \mathbb Z \to \mathcal B_3 \xrightarrow{\rho} \PSl_2(\mathbb Z) \to 1.\end{equation}
What is a good reference for this?

Let's fix some notation: The braid group $\mathcal B_3$ is generated by the elementary twists $A$ and $B$, subject to the braid relation
\begin{equation} \label{braid-relation} \tag{2} ABA = BAB.\end{equation}
The map $\rho$ is given by
$$A \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad B \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
The element $c \in \mathbb B_3$ is $c = (ABA)^2 = (AB)^3$.
So far I have checked:

1. The map $\rho$ is well-defined, i.e. it preserves the braid relation \eqref{braid-relation}.
2. The map $\rho$ is surjective, it hits the typical generators of $\PSl_2(\mathbb Z)$ corresponding to the Möbius transformations $z \mapsto - \frac 1 z$ (this is $\rho(A^{-1})$) and $z \mapsto z + 1$ (this is $\rho(ABA)$).
3. The element $c$ is indeed central (commutes with $A$ and $B$) and is in the kernel of $\rho$.

What I'm still missing is:

1. The kernel of $\rho$ is generated by $c$.
2. The extension $\eqref{extension}$ is universal.

What is a good reference for this? Or is that easily seen?

Comment: See for example [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiarq_Pzo3_AhVvgv0HHarGDEAQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdept.math.lsa.umich.edu%2F~jchw%2FRTG-Braids.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1JMv6JxxltPDQsM0pmbnmh), Exercise $10$. The material before is helpful.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, that looks like a good source of useful exercises! I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article on arXiv where the author studies the relationship between the triaxial group and $\operatorname{PSl}_2(\mathbb Z)$, but the article does not directly state that $\operatorname{PSl}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is a universal central extension of the triaxial group​ [1](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2008.02262)

Regarding the first point, it can be noted that the kernel of a surjective homomorphism can be finitely generated if the original group is finitely generated and the target group is finitely represented [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973413/the-kernel-of-a-surjective-homomorphism-g-rightarrow-mathbbz-is-finitely-gen). This may help you prove that the kernel $\rho$ is generated by the $c$ element.

The universal central extension is defined in such a way that for any other central extension there are unique homomorphisms that ensure the commutativity of the corresponding diagram​ [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension)​. This may give some insight into what "an extension is generic" means.