# What exactly is a universal central extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-cohomology, central-extensions

Let $G$ be a group. In *An introduction to homological algebra*, Chapter 6.9 Weibel defines a universal central extension as a central extension
$$0 \to A \to X \to G \to 1,$$
which is initial with respect to all central extensions. In other words, if $0 \to B \to Y \to G \to 1$ is any other central extension, then there is a unique homomorphism $X \to Y$ which is compatible with the two maps to $G$.

The first basic lemma (6.9.2) Weibel proves is that if there exists a universal central extension, then both $X$ and $G$ are perfect (i.e. $[G,G] = G$).

Now both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_between_B3_and_the_modular_group) and [this notes (Exercise 10)](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ejchw/RTG-Braids.pdf) claim that the extension
$$0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathcal B_3 \to \operatorname{PSl}_2(\mathbb Z) \to 1$$
is universal. (For the definition of the extension, see [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705617/reference-request-universal-central-extension-of-operatornamepsl-2-mathbb?noredirect=1#comment9961504_4705617).)

But that apparently contradicts Weibel's lemma, because the group $\mathcal B_3$ is not perfect, it's abelization is $\mathbb Z$ (by exercise 7 of the above notes). So I guess there is a different notion of *universal* central extension? [This section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier#Relation_to_central_extensions) seems to also indicate that, but I don't quite understand what they mean, and it seems to mostly care about finite groups? Does that make a difference?

Comment: For those of us who (like me) don't know much about your question, it would be helpful it you could state what your symbols stand for. Like: What kind of algebraic objects are your A, X, G ?  Groups?  Abelian groups? Something else? Etc.

Comment: @DanAsimov Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_extension_(mathematics)) for the definition of a central extension. My question was aimed at people who already know that, which  is why I didn't include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question had been discussed at [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224190/in-what-sense-is-the-braid-group-b-3-the-universal-central-extension-of-the-mo). The "usual" definition of a universal central extension $X$ of a group $G$ assumes that $G$ is perfect, and
that it is the unique (up to isomorphism) group $X$ that is a Schur covering group of $G$. In other words, the universal central extension of a perfect group is also *perfect* -
see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Universal_central_extension).

However, the terminology has been also used as follows:  In a universal central extension $1 \to M \to X \to G \to 1$ of $G$, the image of $M$ in $X$ is required to be in the commutator subgroup $[X,X]$ of $X$. In our case,
the intersection of the central cyclic subgroup $\langle x^2 \rangle = \langle y^3 \rangle$ of $B_3$ with $[B_3,B_3]$ is trivial.

Comment: Just to verify I understand this correctly: Any central extension $1 \to M \to X \to G  \to 1$ with $M \subset [X,X]$ is called universal? So the extension $0 \to c \mathbb Z \to B_3 \to \operatorname{PSl}_2(\mathbb Z) \to 1$ is *not* universal in this sense, but still called universal for other reasons?

Comment: Yes, some people say that there is no requirement in general for a universal central extension to be perfect - only that its central subgroup $M$ is in its commutator subgroup.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the non-perfect case? I checked the books by Aschbacher and Rotman, but I think they only cover the perfect case.

Comment: For a reference see for example [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schur_covering_group). It is now mostly called a "Schur cover". But in topology it is called "universal central extension". We have a reference  already, i.e., the one with Exercise $10$.

Comment: Thanks, that is way clearer than the Wikipedia article. The notes by Jenny Wilson do not contain a definition for "universal central extension", or did I miss anything?

Comment: No, but it is used in Exercise 10 with the name "universal central extension", although the group is not perfect. Also, you mentioned it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705617/reference-request-universal-central-extension-of-operatornamepsl-2-mathbb?noredirect=1#comment9961504_4705617), so it was used elsewhere. I suppose one can search fro more references.